# iphone image rotate only parts of the image

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a wheel image in the centre of my iPhone application which rotates. On top of that I put an UIImageView but I do not want this to rotate. Unfortunately it is rotating as well. How can I stop this image from moving as well please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rotate a view, all subviews will rotate too. Just add the view (which shouldn't be animated) to another view as a subview.